# Por que hay varios import de la misma librería

Tags: java, java-swing

Buenas estoy aprendiendo swing y no me queda claro el porqué si he hecho

```
import java.awt.*;
```

Luego he de hacer varios import de la misma librería, por ejemplo

```
import java.awt.*;
import static java.awt.Color.DARK_GRAY;

public class Main extends Frame{
public static void main(String args []){
    Frame sf =new Frame("Mi ventana");
    sf.setSize(500, 500);
    sf.setVisible(true);
    sf.setBackground(DARK_GRAY);
   }   
}
```

No entiendo por que tengo que especificar el `import` `java.awt.Color` o tener que poner en `sf.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY)` para que me tome el color, no se supone que el primer `import` me carga todas las clases de la librería `awt`? 
Gracias

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La linea `import static java.awt.Color.DARK_GRAY` hace uso de un `import estático`.
Un `import estático` se puede usar sobre métodos o propiedades estáticas de una clase concreta, y permite no tener que indicar la clase al usarlos, favoreciendo la legibilidad del código.

Así, si tu código no tuviera ese `static import`, tendrías que haber puesto:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Main extends Frame{
public static void main(String args []){
    Frame sf =new Frame("Mi ventana");
    sf.setSize(500, 500);
    sf.setVisible(true);
    sf.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
   }   
}
```

En este caso puede que no ayude demasiado, pero en otros sí que lo hace, por ejemplo:

```
private List<String> ordenarLista(List<String> lista){
   return aa.stream().sorted(Comparators.nullsLow()).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

añadiendo `static imports`:

```
    import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
    import static org.springframework.util.comparator.Comparators.nullsLow;

    private List<String> ordenarLista(List<String> lista){
       return aa.stream().sorted(nullsLow()).collect(toList());
    }
```

Un import "normal" te evita poner el paquete completo cuando declaras/instancias una clase. Este sería tu código sin imports:

```
public class Main extends java.awt.Frame{
public static void main(String args []){
    java.awt.Frame sf =new java.awt.Frame("Mi ventana");
    sf.setSize(500, 500);
    sf.setVisible(true);
    sf.setBackground(java.awt.Color.DARK_GRAY);
   }   
}
```

Comment: Un import normal te evita tener que poner el paquete completo de la clase para usarla, añado a la respuesta.